# Where is vogue (the nodeJS module), so that I can add it to PATH?

Tags: bash, node.js, installation

I have been following the instructions at http://aboutcode.net/vogue/ - installed nodeJS and npm, with no errors - but when it comes to the step:

$ vogue path/to/website

I get:

-bash: vogue: command not found

How do I find vogue to add it to PATH? I have tried:

find /usr -name vogue -type f

find / -name vogue -type f

...with no joy.

Comment: what version of npm are you using? (npm -v) for npm 1.0.0+ you need to use npm install vogue -g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you install anything via NPM all bin's are in this hidden folder: /node_modules/.bin/
The /node_modules folder gets created relative, from where you run NPM.

Comment: Thank you. From that prod in the right direction I managed to sort it out.